# SharePoint 2007: How to sync profile with Active Directory?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, active-directory

I recently had an incident where the email details of a Sharepoint user were changed in Active Directory. These changes were not transferred into SharePoint and I had a problem in one of my web parts which uses the SPUser object to get the users email address.

Is there a way to configure Sharepoint to synchronise such data automatically?

**Update**

I changed my email address in AD and started a full profile import. I opened my Sharepoint user settings but see no change in my profile - it still shows my old email address

Answer (score 1):

Just run a profile import from Central Admin, either a full or incremental import should update the affected profile.

Comment: Thanks. It's in the SharedServices section. I see that it is already configured for Full import every week and partial every day. Any ideas why the email address changes were not showing up in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've managed to get around this in the past is to dump the profile record that won't update and re-run the import.

Answer (score 0):

This post explains [there are actually both WSS and MOSS profiles](http://sharepointnotes.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/syncing-wss-and-moss-user-profile-properties-with-active-directory/) and that you need to do profile synchronization between them. (If you look at your profile in SSP Admin you probably do see the update after the import runs, but the site itself has not been updated).

Anyway, I'm still trying to get the sync to work (it says it's set up), but I thought the additional info might be helpful even if I haven't yet figured out the whole solution.